# Creating a virtual RPM package with no files and only other dependencies

Tags: rpm, rpmbuild

I'm building FFMPEG into an RPM and I have many subpackages defined. Each subpackage is a shared library that FFMPEG provides, or that shared library's development files, ie `libavcodec-devel`.

I'd like to provide a package called `ffmpeg-devel` which simply depends on all of the other `devel` packages. I'm currently doing the following:

```
%package -n ffmpeg-devel
Summary: ffmpeg-devel
Requires: libavcodec-devel
Requires: libavdevice-devel
Requires: libavfilter-devel
Requires: libavformat-devel
Requires: libavresample-devel
Requires: libavutil-devel
Requires: libpostproc-devel
Requires: libswresample-devel
Requires: libswscale-devel
%description -n ffmpeg-devel
ffmpeg-devel
%files -n ffmpeg-devel
%exclude /*
```

Now, normally, `rpmbuild` will see any unpackaged files in the BUILDROOT for the package and fail the build if anything isn't included or specifically excluded. This is a good thing in my opinion, as it prevents packagers from missing things.

The problem above in my `ffmpeg-devel` virtual package is that it excludes everything, making it impossible for me to see if something wasn't included.

Is there a better way to make empty packages which only include dependencies on other packages?

Comment: If your `%install` section does nothing, the build root should be empty, so just leave the `%files` blank....?

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Aaron, you should leave the %files section out.

A part from that you are doing it right. This meta-package is empty so there are no files to see.

What you are missing is checking with /bin/rpm what dependencies will your package ask for:

```
rpm -qpR my-package.rpm
```

Comment: Actually, I find that leaving out %files altogether results in no binary package, just the .src.rpm.  I can believe that it's my environment, C7 and mock for the dirty work.